# Setting up sp_AllNightLog using Azure Blob Storage

Tags: sql-server, log-shipping, azure, azure-blob-storage

Has anyone setup Brent Ozar's sp_AllNightLog using Azure Blob Storage? Trying to start incorporating both but not sure of the steps or how to get started. Any tips or links to similar operations?

Answer (score 1):

Brent Ozar's [sp_AllNightLog](https://www.brentozar.com/sp_allnightlog/) uses Ola Hallengren's backup script.

> Inside each of those Agent jobs, they call sp_AllNightLog @Backup = 1, which loops through the table to find databases that need to be backed up, then call Ola Hallengren’s DatabaseBackup stored procedure.

So you just need to configure [Ola's script](https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-backup.html) to write to Azure Blob Storage.

> Striping of backups to Azure Blob Storage
>
> The SQLCAT - team has a [blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlcat/2017/03/10/backing-up-a-vldb-to-azure-blob-storage/) post about how you can optimize performance when backing up to Azure Blob Storage. You can stripe the backups to multiple files, and use the options MAXTRANSFERSIZE, and BLOCKSIZE.
>
> ```
> EXECUTE dbo.DatabaseBackup @Databases = 'USER_DATABASES',
> @URL = 'https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer',
> @BackupType = 'FULL',
> @Compress = 'Y',
> @Verify = 'Y',
> @NumberOfFiles = 8,
> @MaxTransferSize = 4194304,
> @BlockSize = 65536
> ```

This is the important part:

```
@URL = 'https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer'
```